# Hello everyone, how can I hide the fullscreen icon in kivy app

Tags: python, kivy

[image: for example]

I searched the internet how to do it but couldn't find it

Comment: Hi, please see here about how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: seems pretty fine and straight to the point if you ask me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible if:

- The window backend (normally SDL2) provides an API for it; and
- Kivy exposes that API

I'm not sure if either of these things is the case, but maybe it's possible on some operating systems with some window backends.

With SDL2 you can tell it not to draw the titlebar and instead draw your own window decorations, in which case you can skip this button, but I don't think Kivy exposes this SDL2 functionality either.

Overall: it's possible, but you will need to experiment and probably modify kivy's code. It may be tricky.

Comment: @Bare somewhere in the kivy code (if this is how you fix it) it should be under the declaration of an ```SDL_Window``` and one of the flags will be ```SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE```